# How to open button click url in default browser or webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

How can I open an url in a `webview` or in the default browser after clicking a button? Currently, when I click the `btn1` button it prompts me to select a browser from the phone. I want to open this url inside the default browser or in a `webview`.

Here is my java code:

```
 public class myactivity extends Activity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_click_login);
    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
             startActivity(myWebLink);
          }
         }
     );
}
```

Comment: you have asked 10 questions but non of them accepted by u. event u have right answers?

Comment: As @imrankhan has alluded too, you'll have better luck getting help if you accept answers that were correct.

Comment: brothers i am not getting the right answer , i will accept if i get one.. sorry i am not having any luck !!!!

Comment: @sam that question is not even answered, i got one answer but that was for android browser not for webview..

Comment: @LaChi Your old question being unanswered is not a reason to post it again you are "littering" the site if you make reposts like this. Also what you want to do is very basic, if you search around on this site and in the Developer Docs you could find countless examples of how to do.

Comment: smells like a repost of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025558/how-to-create-webview-for-button-click-link

Answer (score 21):

Here you go.

Make sure to include `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in manifest

```
Intent internetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
internetIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser","com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
internetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(internetIntent);
```

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

Answer (score 4):

can try this your intent

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
```

in your code

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent myWebLink = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             myWebLink.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity"));
             myWebLink.setData(Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
             startActivity(myWebLink);
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

In android there are two types of intents:

Explicit Intents: where target component is specified, explicitly.
Implicit Intents: Target Component is not specified, instead there are some other fields are provided, which are Data, Action, Category.. and according to these fields(attributes) android system filters activities or components to handle the intent.

And you are using Implicit Intent, and it will list all the activities which can work on Action_VIEW, and specified URI. To avoid this situation you have only option that you can restrict Android system to filter further, by some other parameter, or changing it to Explicit Intent. and To Change it to Explicit Intent you would need target component Name.

Answer (score 1):

put a WebView in your layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"

  android:gravity="center"  
  >

  <WebView 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/web"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Get a reference to it in your activity

```
WebView mWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
```

call loadUrl() on it.

```
mWeb.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Comment: it will simply load this url in webview but i want to load that url which will open when a user will click the button .

Answer (score 1):

This Works For me

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
```