# Apps with same intent names

Tags: android, android-intent

i have two apps that have same intent names called videoPlayer and when i run one of that apps chooser ask me to chose default action for the intent.How can i tell app to  perform action from default package

```
Intent menuIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.Videoplayer");
            startActivity(menuIntent);
```

Comment: this can be set the first time the option comes, as in I have different launchers and when i click home button i can choose if i want my current choice as the default. How will the device know which is the intent you were referring to ?

Comment: Please use your own package name for `Intent` actions. You do not work for the Android project; you should not be creating actions like `android.intent.action.Videoplayer`. Then, if you do not want a chooser to appear, do not use the same action string for both activities. If they are your own private activities, you should not need an `<intent-filter>` for them in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to tell the system to use the preinstalled app over your own?
Android doesn't really work like that. All apps are created equal, system defaults and third party. There isn't really a way to do this without using explicted intent resolution. Your going to have to provide the intent with more information or make your action default using the popup dialog.

Answer (score 0):

use [setComponent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to make it specific .....

```
menuIntent .setComponent(new ComponentName("<package>", "com.android.< Activity >"));
```

like for [How to open button click url in default browser or webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031348/how-to-open-button-click-url-in-default-browser-or-webview/11031564#11031564)